# Make Text view be able to show less and show all by tapping

Tags: swiftui

I want my Text view here to be similar to facebook post. When the text first appear it should display only 5 line limit of words. This text however can be tapped to expand all the text and its background should expand as the text expand too. Does text contains any modifiers to do this? I seemed to find only linelimit() modifier.

```
   struct InsideTab: View {

   @State var fColor = Color.white
   @State var bColor = Color.pink

var body: some View {
    Text("When it comes to chicken there just isn’t anything more delicious than a juicy, crusty piece of finger-licking good fried chicken. It might seem intimidating to fry your own chicken, but it’s actually pretty straightforward and it puts grocery store and fast food fried chicken to shame.  If you have a thermometer for the oil and a timer, you can produce fail-proof fried chicken.  If you’ve ever wanted to make your own fried chicken, now is the time to try!")
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(fColor)
        .background(bColor)
        .font(.system(size: 15))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .lineLimit(5)
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .padding()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by turning your **Text** into a `Button` or add `onTapGesture` to support on click event. Also, add a `@State variable` to determine whether to expand or not expand your text for each click. I added some new code to your provided code. Check lines where I put **//added**. Be noted that you can customize the maximum line limit depends on your own desired design.

Try this code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Testing: View {
@State var fColor = Color.white
@State var bColor = Color.pink
//added
@State var isViewed = false
var body: some View {
    //added
    Button {
        //added
        isViewed.toggle()
    } label: {
        Text("When it comes to chicken there just isn’t anything more delicious than a juicy, crusty piece of finger-licking good fried chicken. It might seem intimidating to fry your own chicken, but it’s actually pretty straightforward and it puts grocery store and fast food fried chicken to shame.  If you have a thermometer for the oil and a timer, you can produce fail-proof fried chicken.  If you’ve ever wanted to make your own fried chicken, now is the time to try!")
            .foregroundColor(fColor)
            .font(.system(size: 15))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(isViewed ? 15 : 5) //added
            .padding()
    }
    .background(bColor)
    .cornerRadius(30)
    .padding()
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked! but can this same way be applied with TextField? my TextField seemed to limit at 1 line

Comment: Actually, this case is already solved in the new beta version of SwiftUI. Your TextField will generate a new line automatically bases on your input amount. If you are using these beta, or will use these in the future, then you don't have to worry about this problem.